# How Query.getResultList() works

Tags: eclipselink, jpql

So I have the follow code.

```
Query query = getEntityManager()
                    .createQuery(
                            "SELECT m.memCategory, m.copClass, SUM(b.paidAmt) paidAmt FROM BuildingFundModel b "
                            + "INNER JOIN b.memberModel m WHERE b.memberModel != NULL AND b.paidDt BETWEEN :dtFrom AND :dtTo "
                            + "GROUP BY m.memCategory, m.copClass");            

query.setParameter("dtFrom", dtFrom);
query.setParameter("dtTo", dtTo);

lstObj = query.getResultList();
```

However, when I run this, it always returns only two columns.  Is that How Query.getResultList() should work?

Comment: No, it should return 3. What is the SQL query being generated and executed? What is the code of the involved entities? Note that `!= null` should be `is not null`. But even then, this clause is useless: an inner join will never be done on a null memberModel.

Comment: I checked the SQL being fired and it has only two columns on it.  What the hell is going on in here?

Comment: Which two columns then?  What are the memCategory and copClass mappings?

Answer (score 0):

This query will return a list containing one or more Object[].  The number of items in the list correlates to the number of rows returned, while each Object[] should contain 3 items, one for each column.

Comment: Yes.  I understand how it should work.  However, my problem is that it is returning only two of the three columns that it should be getting.

Answer (score 0):

The `Query.getResultList()` method replaces the place holders in the query with the variables from the `query.setParameter`. It then executes the query returning what is selected in the `SELECT` statement.
Try this query:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
"SELECT m.memCategory, m.copClass, SUM(b.paidAmt)
 FROM BuildingFundModel b 
 INNER JOIN b.memberModel m 
 WHERE b.memberModel IS NOT NULL AND b.paidDt BETWEEN :dtFrom AND :dtto
 GROUP BY m.memCategory,m.copClass");

query.setParameter("dtFrom", dtFrom);
query.setParameter("dtTo", dtTo);

lstObj = query.getResultList();
```